# Spring MVC, Return ModelAndView statements are ignored in Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, modelandview

I have following app setup.

- The dispatcher servlet is matched to the `*.htm` URL pattern.
- Controller has the annotation `@RequestMapping(value = "doSuccess")`
- The method for the above annotation just returns `new ModelAndView("success");`

---

```
 <bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" 
      p:order="1"/>
```

---

- The index page has the link

---

```
<a href="doSuccess.htm">Click me</a>
```

---

- There is a file called `success.jsp` located in `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

Now, when I click on the Click me, I get a 404. I did a bit of debugging and realized that the method in the controller was indeed being called but irrespective of the return statement it is trying to find `doSuccess.htm`.

Comment: Please show us the config, rather than describing it. Did you tell Spring to look in `/jsp`?

Comment: what is the href of the Click me link?

Comment: Is `success.jsp` in `/jsp/`, or `/WEB-INF/jsp/`?

Comment: Could someone explain when a return ModelAndView("xyz") statement is ignored or overridden to return some other page (in this case the initial htm page that was in the link!)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured the error. I was using Netbeans and i used the auto complete imports. It was importing the org.springframework.web.**portlet**.ModelAndView instead of **servlet**.ModelAndView.